# Subquery Select as field in SQL- Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, bcp

I needed to display the subquery results as field and exporting to csv using BCP.

This is my query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    NAME [NAME],
    CODE [CUSTOMER CODE],
    FROMDATE [FROMDATE],
    TODATE [TODATE]
INTO
    ##temp 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT 
         g.NAME AS NAME,
         g.ACCOUNTNUM AS CODE,
         d.FROMDATE, d.TODATE
     FROM 
         GeneralInfo g 
     INNER JOIN 
         DateInfo d ON g.id = d.generalId)
```

So whenever I exported to CSV the file format was as expected due to name field. I needed to enclose the field with "". But somehow I ended up with an error. Please advise

Comment: Is this complete query ? do you want to select a column using sub query ? you need to tag database you are using.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error? And which RDBMS ??

Comment: My project is on MSSQL and tried to execute in SSMS tool. The error says g.NAME is a invalid column when i used like "g.NAME" so that my resultant bcp-csv file will consider as a single field.

Comment: If you want to export this query results into csv - why do you use temp table? Why sub-query?

Comment: Try removing whitespace from the column names.  Try changing CODE [CUSTOMER CODE], to CODE [CUSTOMERCODE],